# How to position elements in a div such that they move where the div moves

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am trying to build a simple div based popup which can be used to display messages and other stuff. I am using jqueryui position function to position the div in the appropriate place in the page.

The issue is that the while the div is positioned correctly, the elements inside it are not. That is the div is at the center of the screen, whereas the select elements within the div are at the bottom of the page.

What is the best way to make the div behave like a box such that the elements inside it also move where the div moves?

-- Edit - Adding sample markup below --

```
    <div class="divpopupsmall" id="ctl00_cp1_JobCategoryCitySelect" style="position:          relative; top: 93.2px; left: 278.5px;">



        <div>
            <select class="popupboxelement" id="ctl00_cp1_ddlJobCategory" name="ctl00$cp1$ddlJobCategory">
    <option value="0">Driver</option>
    <option value="1">Maid</option>
    <option value="2">Cook</option>
    <option value="3">Nanny</option>
    <option value="4">Gardener</option>
    <option value="5">Guard</option>
    <option value="6">Laborer</option>
    <option value="7">Garment Worker</option>
    <option value="8">Office Helper</option>
    <option value="9">Delivery Helper</option>
    <option value="10">Receptionist</option>
    <option value="11">Other</option>
    <option value="12">Maid cum Cook</option>
    <option value="13">Data Entry</option>
    <option value="14">Cashier</option>
    <option value="15">Nurse-maid</option>
    <option value="16">IT Pro</option>
    <option value="17">Machinist</option>
    <option value="18">Sales Rep</option>
    <option value="19">BPO Call Center</option>
    <option value="20">Management</option>
    <option value="21">Teacher</option>
    <option value="22">Finance</option>
    <option value="23">Engineer</option>
</select>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.divpopupsmall{border: 7px solid  rgba(150,150,150,0.2); width:400px; height:200px;z-index:700;background-color:#fff;-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #aaaaaa;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #aaaaaa;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #aaaaaa;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;}
 .popupboxelement{position:absolute;}
```

This is the markup from the actual HTML source taken via Firebug. The style attribute for the .divpopupsmall is added by the jqueryui.position function.

Comment: Can you supply example html of your popup-div.

Comment: please show some code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there is an intermediate div which was the container to the .popupboxelement and the positioning for this intermediate div was not set (i.e. it was the default value which is 'static') (see markup in question)

I changed the positioning of the intermediate div and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the css position for the divs.

.divpopupsmall should be position: absolute;
.popupboxelement should be position: relative;

```
.divpopupsmall{ position: absolute; ... }
.popupboxelement{ position:relative; ... }
```

**OR**

Remove the position css from .popupboxelement entirely and leave the .divpopupsmall as position: relative;

```
.divpopupsmall{ position: relative; ... }
.popupboxelement{ ... }
```

Extra Info:

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the browser window , unless the parent element has a position property set to anything but the default "static" - (Alex)

Relatively positioned elements are positioned relative to their parent element.

Comment: Should work tho. For some information: absolutely/fixed positioned elements are positioned in reference to the browser window, unless the parent element has a position property set to anything but the default "static"

Comment: As Alex mentioned, it should've worked. The issue was there because there was an intermediate div (as you can see in the markup above) and its positioning wasnt set.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
#floating { position:relative; height: 100px; width: 100px; background:#ccc; padding:5px; left: 50px; top: 50px }
.info { position:absolute }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="floating">
  <div class="info"> Here is your info</div>
</div>
```

***NOTE:***

You can chage `position` of THE CONTAINER BOX & its INNER ELEMENT.

Comment: here positioning is the main issue. now you just change the `left` and `top` of the `#floating` i.e. the container box and the whole content will move with it..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery UI already, why not use their own [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)?

Comment: The jquery dialog has the close button and I dont want the user to be able to close the dialog unless some action is performed. I am not sure if you can get rid of the close button on the jqueryui dialog. Can you?